# VS2010: View method comments in preview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I usually add a short description to every method that I create. And when I go to *Method Definition* I can read this description/comment and I know what the method does.

Is it possible to see these comments in the method preview? For example, if I put my cursor over an invoked method, a small popup will show with the method signature. Is it possible to also see the method comments when the cursor's over the method?

I don't want to have to go to the actual method to see what it does.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't remember about VS2010, but VS2013 does it... Maybe time for an upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You need to add your comments as a `summary` element using the [C# XML Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b2s063f7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) format.

```
class MyClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Does something.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="foo">The input.</param>
    /// <returns>The result.</returns>
    public int DoSomething(string foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
        return 3;
    }
}
```

With the documentation defined as above, Intellisense provides the following:

[image: XML Doc Intellisense example in Visual Studio]

Answer (score 1):

Use XML comments. These should be visible when you use Intellisense.

Example:

```
/// <summary>
///  This class performs an important function.
/// </summary>
public class MyClass{}
```

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b2s063f7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx